# how to iterate through an array list of class type

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I have two classes A and B. I want to access an array list in A from B. The array list is of class C type, which stores objects(packets). I would like to know if there is any way to iterate through the list and get specific data from each packet.

```
public class PcapStream
{
  PcapParser objPcapParser = new PcapParser();
  PcapDef numPackets = new PcapDef();
  int listSize = numPackets.getMaxPackets();

  public void findStream()
  {
    final ListIterator<PcapDef> packetIterator = objPcapParser.packet_list.listIterator();
    while(packetIterator.hasNext())
    {
      for(final int i=0; i<=listSize;i++)
      {
```

I started off with something like this. Not sure how it works. Class B is PcapStream, Class A is PcapParser, Class C is PcapDef

```
ListIterator packetIterator = objPcapParser.packet_list.listIterator();
    while(packetIterator.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++ )
      {
        PcapDef packet1 = (PcapDef) packetIterator.next();
        PcapDef packet2 = packetIterator; //here I would like to get the 2nd object from the list, not sure how to get that at this point.
      }
}
public int compare(final PcapDef packet1, final PcapDef packet2)
  {

   return 0; 
  }
```

I'm still working on it. At this point this is what I have

```
    public void findStream()
      {
          try
          {
            for(int i=0;i<listSize;i++)
            {
              final List <PcapDef> list = new ArrayList<PcapDef>();
              final PcapDef packet1 = objPcapParser.packet_list.get(i);
              checkPackets(packet1, list, i);
            }
          }
          catch(final IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
          {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
          }
        final Set packetSet = Stream.entrySet();
        final Iterator setIterator = packetSet.iterator();
        while(setIterator.hasNext())
        {
          final Map.Entry packetEntry = (Map.Entry) setIterator.next();
          System.out.print(packetEntry.getKey() + ": ");
          System.out.println(packetEntry.getValue());
        }
      }

      private void checkPackets(final PcapDef packet1, final List<PcapDef> list, final int i)
      {
        for(int j=1;j<listSize && j!=i;j++)
        {
          final PcapDef packet2 = objPcapParser.packet_list.get(j);
          final int value = compare(packet1,packet2);
          if(value == 0)
          {
            list.add(packet1);
list.add(packet2);
            checkPackets(packet2, list, i);
          }
          else
          {
            Stream.put(i,list); //add list to hashmap
          }
        }

      }

      @Override
      public int compare(final PcapDef packet1, final PcapDef packet2)
      {
        final String header1 = packet1.getHeader();
        final String header2 = packet2.getHeader();
        final String src_port1 = packet1.getSrc_port();
        final String dst_port2 = packet2.getDst_port();
final String src_port2 = packet2.getSrc_port();
        final String dst_port1 = packet1.getDst_port();
        System.out.println(header1 + header2);
        int flag = 1;
        try{
          if(header1.equalsIgnoreCase(header2))
          {
            if((src_port1.substring(10).equalsIgnoreCase(dst_port2.substring(10))) && (src_port2.substring(10).equalsIgnoreCase(dst_port1.substring(10)) )
            {
              flag = 0;
              return flag;
            }
          }
        }
```

@Andy This is what I wrote so far. Problems I'm facing: Duplicates are being generated and hashmap entries are not continuous, I mean like index 0,1,2.. instead few locations are empty. Due to this if I give very large files as input to my program it is throwing me an indexoutofboundsexception. I'm a beginner and trying my best. Kindly, help.

Comment: And why wouldn't there be? Show us what you have so far, otherwise you cannot have any answer

Comment: public class PcapStream
{
  PcapParser objPcapParser = new PcapParser();
  PcapDef numPackets = new PcapDef();
  int listSize = numPackets.getMaxPackets();

  public void findStream()
  {
    final ListIterator<PcapDef> packetIterator = objPcapParser.packet_list.listIterator();
    while(packetIterator.hasNext())
    {
      for(final int i=0; i<=listSize;i++)............. I started of with something like this, but I do not know how it works

Comment: Put this in your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Iterator.next()` method to get the next list member. Each call to next() advances to the next list member.

```
while(packetIterator.hasNext())
{
  PCapDef packet = packetIterator.next();
  ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

And you can use the `Iterator.get(int)` method to get a list member by index.

```
while(packetIterator.hasNext())
{
  PCapDef packet = packetIterator.next();

  for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++ )
  {
    PcapDef packet2 = objPcapParser.packet_list.get( i )
    ...
  }    
}
```

Comment: I did that. My list is a list of objects whose values I wish to compare. I'm trying to override the compare method. If you have any suggestions to make, kindly let me know

Comment: Your question didn't mention the compare() method. Show us what you have so far.

Comment: ListIterator packetIterator = objPcapParser.packet_list.listIterator();
    while(packetIterator.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++ )
      {
        PcapDef packet1 = (PcapDef) packetIterator.next();
        PcapDef packet2 = packetIterator;
      }

Comment: Put this in your question, not in a comment, after ensuring that it compiles.

Comment: @Shanti - I'm guessing from the nested loop that you want to access the other list member by index (e.g., maybe to compare all list members against all others). I've added an example of how to get a list member by index. I've moved the next() call into the outer loop - otherwise, it would advance in each iteration of the inner loop.